# Syntax error in Sql MS-Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

My question: the owners would like to know the revenue generated so far (i.e. `where CheckOutDate < DATE()`)  for each room type in each hotel.

The calculation must be done in the SQL statement.

Determine the length of stay for each reservation (i.e. number of days) using the DateDiff function `datediff('d', checkindate, checkoutdate)` and multiply this value by the room rate.

Your output should be formatted as shown on the next page. Your Revenue totals may be different. Keep in mind, the Revenue amount may change on a daily basis, as we want to include only those reservations that are completed, not current or future reservations.

```
select 
   room.hotelID, room.roomtype,
   datediff('d', Reservation.CheckOutDate, Reservation.CheckInDate) * ROOM_TYPE.RoomRate as Revenue 
from 
   Reservation 
inner join 
   Room on Room.hotelID = Reservation.HotelID 
inner join 
   ROOM_TYPE on ROOM_TYPE.RoomType = Room.roomtype 
group by 
   Room.HotelID, Room.roomtype;
```

I am getting syntax error statement missing in this.

How to resolve this error in MS Access?

Comment: Please put your code in a code clock so it is formatted correctly.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am new. I dont know how to do that.

Comment: In the text box where you type in your question, there is a toolbar across the top of it.  One of the tool buttons looks like, "{}".  Hover over it.  Clicking on it will make any currently selected text into a code block.

Comment: Your error is probably related to the group by. The third column needs to be an aggregate.

Comment: @shawnt00 Yeah i made that sum(datediff('d', Reservation.CheckOutDate, Reservation.CheckInDate) * ROOM_TYPE.RoomRate) yet the error is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the query below against your data in Access 2010 produced this result set:

```
hotelID roomtype Revenue
------- -------- ----------
1000    D        $23,000.00
1000    F        $23,100.00
1000    S        $20,700.00
1111    D        $36,500.00
1111    F        $16,450.00
1111    S        $15,300.00
```

```sql
SELECT
    rm.hotelID,
    rm.roomtype,
    Sum(DateDiff('d', rs.CheckInDate, rs.CheckOutDate) * rt.RoomRate) AS Revenue
FROM
    (
        ROOM AS rm INNER JOIN RESERVATION AS rs
        ON (rm.roomno = rs.RoomNo) AND (rm.hotelID = rs.HotelID)
    )
    INNER JOIN ROOM_TYPE AS rt
    ON rm.roomtype = rt.RoomType
WHERE rs.CheckOutDate < Date()
GROUP BY rm.hotelID, rm.roomtype;
```

Answer (score 2):

When using a Group By clause, any columns that are not part of the grouping must be aggregated.  In your case, Room.HotelID and Room.RoomType are the grouping columns.  So they are fine in your SELECT clause, as-is.  But Revenue needs to be aggregated.  I expect that you will want to use the SUM aggregation to sum up all of the Revenue values for each room type.  Try this...

```
select room.hotelID,
       room.roomtype,
       SUM( datediff(day,Reservation.CheckOutDate,Reservation.CheckInDate )*ROOM_TYPE.RoomRate) as Revenue 
from Reservation 
inner join Room on Room.hotelID=Reservation.HotelID 
inner join ROOM_TYPE on ROOM_TYPE.RoomType=Room.roomtype 
group by Room.HotelID, Room.roomtype;
```

Comment: I got you why you used sum and this shall be put before. But I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I edited my answer.  The value of `'d'` for the first parameter of datediff was invalid.  I corrected it to `day`.  I don't know if this is the syntax error that you are getting, but it was an error that needed to be fixed.  (I tested my datediff syntax in MS SQL Server.  It may not be the same for Access.)

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Room.hotelID=Reservation.HotelID 
inner join ROOM_TYPE on ROOM_TYPE.RoomType=Room.roomtype 
group by Room.HotelID, Room.roomtyp'.

Comment: Still the same error If i only run the datediff('d',CheckOutDate,CheckInDate) from reservation; 
It works fine. So I guess there is no error in the datediff() function. To me also this shall work fine in MySql but i dont have an idea with MS Access

Comment: Use the Access query designer to set up your joins.  It will add parentheses in the `FROM` clause which are required to keep Access happy with a query which includes more than one join.

Comment: @HansUp This seems to me the solution. But how to do that? I am new to MS Access

Comment: Here is the link to MS Access
 https://s3.amazonaws.com/iedu-attachments-message/34961b0d08f58efac4ac1682cbfc5f31_01c4ad68f45af1203b978570d1e81c6e.accdb

Comment: [Access 2013 Tutorial Joining Tables in a Query](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5PToZAXbTE)

Answer (score 0):

You should still learn how to use the Query Builder but I think the parens should look something like this:

```
select
    Room.HotelID, Room.roomtype,
    sum(
        datediff('d',Reservation.CheckOutDate,Reservation.CheckInDate) *
        ROOM_TYPE.RoomRate
    ) as Revenue 
from
    ((Reservation inner join Room on Room.hotelID = Reservation.HotelID)
    inner join ROOM_TYPE on ROOM_TYPE.RoomType = Room.roomtype)
group by
    Room.HotelID, Room.roomtype;
```

So in summary:

1. Be careful with grouping columns and aggregates
2. Access uses quotes around it's datediff argument unlike some other systems
3. Nesting of joins needs parentheses

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access we have to mention in brackets () on the clause in from statement. Apart from that datediff function has to be a part of aggregate function.